# Are online index REBUILD operation possible on every Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, index, azure-sql-database, online-operations

I am trying to find informations about the possibility to operate online index REORGANIZE/REBUILD on a database.

What I actually found in the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#defragmenting-indexes-by-rebuilding-or-reorganizing-the-index) is that:

> Reorganizing an index uses minimal system resources and is an online operation.
>
> Depending on the type of index and database engine version, a rebuild operation can be done online or offline.

The documentation is also indicating that:

> Online index operations are not available in every SQL Server edition. For more information, see Editions and supported features of SQL Server.

If I follow the link giving more details about the differences between the multiple SQL Server editions, it says that "Online index create and rebuild" is only supported by "Enterprise Editions".

But now I would like to have more information about the possibility to operate online index REBUILD on Azure SQL database and I cannot find any explicit documentation page about it.

- Is there any limitation on Azure SQL databases too?
- Or online index REBUILD is possible for any Azure SQL database?

Does someone have some documentation link to share or anymore information about this specific point?

Comment: You have option of index rebuild on Azure SQL Server database, but most likely it is not required. Kindly read this [Stackoverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681024/how-to-set-azure-sql-to-rebuild-indexes-automatically) before proceeding

Comment: Actually, if I check my index fragmentation on Azure SQL Server databases, it is quite huge. Do you know if these index rebuild operations are possible on online databases in Azure?

Comment: Yes it is possible, again if you refer the link I have posted you would find a way to do that

Comment: @Shanky I just read the thread you posted above and does not understand. The validated answer clearly says that index rebuild is, in a big majority of the cases, not required. But, like the author of the topic, I have a huge amount of fragmented tables (higher than 99). And some queries taking a lot of time are really faster after an index rebuild. Besides, I just tested an index rebuild on my online Azure database and that locked the tables during the operation. What's the point on doing it on an online db if that locks the tables?

Comment: For Index rebuild the answerer mentioned "in most cases", I believe you case is nit different due to different category storage you chose. YES online index rebuild does takes lock ( 2 short term locks) see Myth 5 in [This Blog](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-19-misconceptions-around-index-rebuilds-allocation-bulk_logged-mode-locking/)

Comment: Really interesting. Thanks for the sharing, I did not know that. So that means index rebuild on online databases are possible in Azure but will cause some locks (short ones). However, I still cannot understand why my tables are this much fragmented. I am not using specific storage so I should be "in most cases"...

Comment: We are mainly talking about periodic index rebuild operations which are not required on Azure databases in most cases. But does index reorganize are? Because, as far as I know, index reorganize are much less impacting the database.

Comment: Index reorganize are lighter but again they also put some impact on system when run. For why index is getting fragmented quickly their could be many reasons